# Remove comments speed

Tags: support

Today I flagged a couple of comments and they got deleted almost immediately.  No moderators were on.

Is there a bot that will auto delete based on the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. See: [Who has the power to delete a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99812/who-has-the-power-to-delete-a-comment/99853#99853)